# "if time allows" or "if time permits"?

Tags: comparison

"if time allows" or "if time permits"? Which one is better in which case?

They look identical to me. 
But I suspect the second is more suitable in written English?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

IMO, both are interchangeable but then there's a subtle difference.

While *allow* simply favors someone, *permission* sounds more authoritative. [Reference dictionary](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/allow?&path=/) supports this.

*Allow's* history is interesting (on the same page).

> 1250–1300; Middle English alowen  < Anglo-French al ( l ) o ( u ) er  to place, allot, allow, Old French aloer  to place < Late Latin allocāre;  see al-, locus; the older sense “approve, sanction” and Middle English  sense “praise” probably by taking the Anglo-French  v. as representing Medieval Latin, Latin adlaudāre  to praise; see ad-, laud

Now, in your case, it's the *time* and not an authority (such as government) or a person so either word can go. But had it been some government (for instance), the above statement may be considered.